# Joomla: Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, cpanel, whm

I am haveing a HUGE issue this morning. We upgraded our server this morning from a VPS to a Dedicated server. All of my sites on the new server worked fine when loading them directly. Example:

on the VPS: https:///~tendesig/zinkcalls.com/
on the Dedicated: https:///~tendesig/zinkcalls.com/

Given that everything appeared to be in order, I went ahead and flipped the switch and repointed my nameservers and host name to the IP of the new box.

Now everything seems to be working for all my sites except for one...

the above links would normally be for https://zinkcalls.com and while the load fine when loading it directly through IP, when loading it by the domain I am getting:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.
```

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Unable_to_connect_to_the_database

Comment: thanks, but yea ive checked all that out. not my first rodeo! the fact is that it connects to the database fine when the site is loaded driectly via IP/~user/site.com but i get the SQL error when the site is loaded vie the domain.

Comment: @TENDesign does the connection use an ip or a hostname? Because if it's the hostname, maybe the DNS that the server uses isn't up to date yet.

Comment: yea both the new box and the old box use the same hostname/nameservers. i kinda though it might be a propagation issue, but then my staging versions which are on subdomains appear to be working fine, as well as every other single site on the box except this one.  "All laws of physics cease to exist in your kitchen alone ~ My Cousin Vinnie"

Comment: possibly an SSL issue?

Comment: Try adding the new IP/Domain to your local hosts file.  If you can load the website without issue then its most likely and DNS propagation issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It turns out the issue was the SSL certs were incorrect. As soon as I update them, every thing worked fine.